Riverpod's ref.read() with param returns loading state on call
So I need to get the result from the following provider:
ExpansionTile(
  onExpansionChanged: (isExpanding) {
    if (isExpanding) {
      final result = ref.read(leaveDetailsProvider(value.items[index].id));
      result.when(data: (value) {
        logger.i(value);
      }, error: (error, trace) {
        logger.e(error);
      }, loading: () {
        logger.i('Loading...');
      });
    }
  }
);

ref.read() always return loading state if not initialized first and it's expected. On the other hand, leaveDetailsProvider accepts a param so I didn't initialize it using ref.watch() inside build method because that means I will have to run ref.watch() using every param available which doesn't make sense.
What is the solution, then? I know something is wrong but I can't find the answer so far.

.when is used to resolve an AsyncValue to either loading, error, or data based on its current state. This is typically used in places where you consume the provider in a reactive manner, such as another provider's body, widget's build method, or notifier's build method.
If you want to get data from an async provider in a callback, read for its future property and use await.
onExpansionChanged: (isExpanding) async {
  if (isExpanding) {
    final leaveDetails = await ref.read(leaveDetailsProvider(value.items[index].id).future);
    // ...
  }
}


Thanks, man. Is the future property documented in the reference manual? I don't remember seeing it explained in the tutorial.

It's first introduced in Combining requests, which basically tells us to use .future whenever we want to have a Future instead of AsyncValue when consuming an async provider.
